# How to check document mode and browser mode without using F12 developer tool

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Is there any way to check the document mode in IE 11 as we want to check without using F12 developer tool . we are testing for our project as we can not ask users to enable the F12 developer tool but we want to check what document and browser mode is there for the customer.

Please suggest any way to check the document mode at least without using F12 developer tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121016/how-to-get-browser-document-mode

Answer (score 0):

document.documentMode in JavaScript should work.

Comment: Please suggest , without using at code level as we have already developed a software and some customer is facing a problem so, we can not ask customer to do code level changes.